# Upload PDF file and Read Issue for Slow Internet Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am working on an application where I need to upload a PDF file and read that file. I am using ITextSharp for reading the file. The application works fine if the end user is using a high internet speed connection. But in case of slow internet speed the upload of the file takes time and an error is thrown. The file size is around 2 MB which is not that big but still I am facing this issue.
Below is the code used for uploading the pdf and reading.

```
if (flUpld.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(flUpld.PostedFile.FileName);
            if (ext == ".pdf")
            {
                string filename = "Test" + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".pdf";
                filePath = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDFLocation"]) + filename;
                // saving PDF
                flUpld.PostedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                //reading PDF 
                data = val.fetchValue(filePath);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming problem. It also doesn't sound like an iTextSharp problem. I'm wondering what kind of answer you expect...

Comment: You also neglected to mention the error you are receiving.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am wondering is there any work around. Where application processing can wait till the pdf is correctly uploaded.   So that for further execution the complete PDF is present.

Comment: I see that you are saving the file on the server side. Normally the part that says `//reading PDF` shouldn't start until the part that says `//saving PDF` has finished saving the document. That fact that this doesn't happen indicates an error in the file upload. My guess is that you are confronted with a time-out that causes some files to be truncated (cut in half, so to speak). Maybe you should increase the time-out value of your server. I don't know for sure because IMHO this is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm with Bruno so I'm going to remove the iTextSharp tag. If anything this is more of a general ASP.Net and/or server config problem.